# valgrind Address 0x421688c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd for linked list having integer data

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

Although there were multiple threads related to

> valgrind Address 0x421688c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd

kind of questions, but all were expressed with either strlen, or '\0' related issues and I understand them. I am having with linked list insertion dealing with integers.

```
void insert_node(lnode **head, int num){
    lnode *temp = NULL;

    temp = calloc(1, sizeof(lnode *));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Memory Allocation failed!\n");
        return;
    }   
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = temp;
    }   
    else{
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }   
}
```

I did insertion, deletion steps and get summary(showing last few lines of valgrind errors as the errors are at the same place):

```
    > ==3238== 9 errors in context 5 of 5:
    > ==3238== Invalid read of size 4
    > ==3238==    at 0x804873D: display (in /home/skb/santosh_practice/linked_list_progs/single_LL/a.out)
    > ==3238==    by 0x8048636: main (in /home/skb/santosh_practice/linked_list_progs/single_LL/a.out)
    > ==3238==  Address 0x42168fc is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
    > ==3238==    at 0x402C17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
    > ==3238==    by 0x8048686: insert_node (in /home/skb/santosh_practice/linked_list_progs/single_LL/a.out)
    > ==3238==    by 0x8048614: main (in /home/skb/santosh_practice/linked_list_progs/single_LL/a.out)
    > ==3238== 
    > ==3238== ERROR
ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof(lnode *)` -> `sizeof(lnode)`

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I tried and got fixed but why is it so? the memory allocation is for pointer!

Comment: No; you need enough space for the structure, and will be given a pointer to that much space.

Comment: You should create a whole program for your [mcve], and compile it with debug symbols, so that the Valgrind output contains source line numbers.

Comment: I already did that. I just put here the last few lines of valgrind summary because I know the problem lied only at one line. Also, had I been put the complete code and valgrind, it would have filled with few pages. Whatever I provided in question, is very much clear to viewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the size that you allocated.

```
lnode *temp = NULL;

temp = calloc(1, sizeof(lnode *));
```

It must be

```
lnode *temp = NULL;

temp = calloc(1, sizeof(lnode));
```

If your structure take 18 octet in memory, and a pointer take 8 octet, with the first code, you will allocate 8 octet instead of 18, which is insuffisent.

a good trick to never have the wrong type is to do

```
lnode *temp = NULL;

temp = calloc(1, sizeof(*temp));
```

Because "temp" is type of "lnode *" and "*temp" is type of "lnode"

Comment: that was pretty well thought! `temp = calloc(1, sizeof(*temp));`, it made me sense that memory allocation is for the contents' size what it will store, not the pointer's size. Thanks!

Comment: No need for parens when you give an *expression* to `sizeof` - that's only needed if you want the size of a *type*.  `temp = calloc(1, sizeof *temp)` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating space for a *pointer* to `lnode`, actually the size of *any* pointer on your platform (4 bytes on a 32 bit system, 8 bytes on a 64 bit system), but you need to allocate space for the struct `lnode` which is the thing the pointer points to.

- `sizeof(lnode *)` is the size of the *pointer* (usually 4 bytes on a 32 bit system or 8 bytes on a 64 bit system.
- `sizeof(lnode)` is the size of the struct `lnode` which depends on how the struct is defined.